# How do I parse timestamps for skyfield?

Tags: timestamp, pyephem, skyfield

Given a UTC timestamp (e.g. the string `'2006-03-01 11:18:15.500000+11:00'`), how should I convert it to a `Time` object in `skyfield` (successor of `pyEphem`)?

For example, can `skyfield` use standard python `datetime` objects?

Answer (score 2):

```py
>>> import dateutil.parser, skyfield.api
>>> ts = skyfield.api.load.timescale()
>>> t = ts.utc(dateutil.parser.parse('2006-03-01 11:18:15.500000+11:00'))
>>> t.utc_datetime() # just to confirm
datetime.datetime(2006, 3, 1, 0, 18, 15, 500000, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Notice that `skyfield.api.Timescale.utc` can take a single `datetime` object for input, instead of a sequence of components (so don't be confused by its call signature in the docs).